# replacing pandas cell "none" with data from the cell below

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'll keep this brief as I'm sure there is a simple solution.

I have two pandas series:

```
s1 = [['name', 'date', 'issue', 'None', height', 'None', 'age']]
s2 = [['eg.john','european format', 'eg. no power', 'first occurence?', 'eg. 1.2m', 'change?', 'eg. 32 years']]
```

There are two `np.Nans` in s1 that I would like to replace with the values in the cell below.

So for example, index 3 in s1 is 'None' and I would like to replace that with the value at index 3 in s2, which is 'first occurrence'.

I would want to get

```
s1 = [['name', 'date', 'issue', 'first occurence', 'height', 'change?', 'age']]
```

I have tried to do this with various for and if statements to no avail, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do it using pandas

```
s1 = [['name', 'date', 'issue', None, 'height', None, 'age']]
s2 = [['eg.john','european format', 'eg. no power', 'first occurence?', 'eg. 1.2m', 'change?', 'eg. 32 years']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(s1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(s2)

new_df = df1.fillna(df2)
```

Output = `name  date  issue  first occurence?  height  change?  age`

Comment: No problem! Take it easy

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 lists not 2 `pd.Series` data types.
Given data:

```
s1 = ['name', 'date', 'issue', 'None', 'height', 'None', 'age']
s2 = ['eg.john','european format', 'eg. no power', 'first occurence?', 'eg. 1.2m', 'change?', 'eg. 32 years']
```

simple solution is to use list comprehension:

```
[e1 if e1!='None' else e2 for e1, e2 in zip(s1, s2)]
```

result:

```
 ['name', 'date', 'issue', 'first occurence?', 'height', 'change?', 'age']
```

Please note 'None' in Your data is not `np.nan` but string.
However if data contains None type all calculations are even simpler:

```
s1 = ['name', 'date', 'issue', None, 'height', None, 'age']
[e1 if e1 else e2 for e1, e2 in zip(s1, s2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, can you direct me to resources for how I could have asked this question better?

Comment: Sorry, this issue is that I wanted to accomplish this with 2 rows of a pandas dataset. Although changing the rows to lists would allow me to use your solution, the answer i have marked as correct got to the heart of what I have asked.